# What is the advantage of "static char const * const" over "static const char" for Associated Object keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I read on the topic of Associated Objects, which lets you create fake properties for categories.

[This article](http://www.sebastianrehnby.com/blog/2013/01/24/associated-objects-by-example/) suggests you define the key simply like this:

```
static const char kNumberKey;
```

It looks uninitialized but works.

And [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/) suggests you do something much more complex:

```
static char const * const ObjectTagKey = "ObjectTag";
```

Is there an advantage in this longer form? I can see it is initialized. But why const * const? And why does the uninitialized variant above work?

Comment: This line is incorrect because "ObjectTag" is array of chars (string), so it should be static *char const *const objectTagKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, `kNumberKey` is a single non-modifiable character with a zero value. So it's not usable directly as a key (you would have to take the address of the character, like this : `&kNumberKey`.

In the second example, `ObjectTagKey` is a non-modifiable pointer to a string of non-modifiable characters.

What does *modifiable* mean in this context? If the pointer is modifiable, you can do this in your code :

> ObjectTagKey = "my new key";

If the characters are modifiable, you can do this :

> ObjectTagKey[3] = 'X';

Having the pointer be non-modifiable helps avoid changing it accidentally, later on in the application's development cycle when development staff has forgotten what `ObjectTagKey` was used for in the first place. The same logic holds for the characters themselves. So it's safer from a software-maintenance perspective.